# Creating Index based on Multiple Variables

Tags: r, date, indexing

I am looking into creating indexes in R but haven't found quite what I'm looking for to index for multiple variables.  I'd like it to reset when variable 1 changes as well.  I have tried `FinalTableMBA$index <- as.numeric(seq_along(FinalTableMBA$Column_2))`, but can't seem to figure out how to add in the second variable to have the index reset.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

For example, I am hoping to accomplish the following:

```
Column 1     Column 2    Index
10/1/2013    10/1/2013     1
10/1/2013    10/2/2013     2.....
10/1/2013    10/30/2013    30
11/1/2013    11/1/2013     1
11/1/2013    11/2/2013     2
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean with "index"? Do you want to number the rows, but restart from 1 when the value of `Column 1` changes?

Comment: look at `?diff` and look at the `data.table` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `by` to split your data by the first column and apply this tricky function to each splitted group :

```
 dat$Index <- unlist(by(dat$Column2,dat$Column1,function(x)
      as.integer(as.factor(as.character(x)))))
 Column1    Column2 Index
1 10/1/2013  10/1/2013     1
2 10/1/2013  10/2/2013     2
3 10/1/2013 10/30/2013     3
4 11/1/2013  11/1/2013     1
5 11/1/2013  11/2/2013     2
```

But I think it is better to format your column2 to a regular date and use `format(x,'%d')` on it.

```
dat$Index <- unlist(by(dat$Column2,dat$Column1,function(x) 
        as.numeric(format(as.Date(x,format='%m/%d/%Y'),'%d'))))
```

Comment: `by` seems forced here.. it's a wrapper of `tapply` essentially, and here you just need `tapply`. So why using by? Especially if you use it in a `tapply` fashion... `by(vector1, vector2, fun)`. Its convenience is in supplying multiple `INDICES`. At that point, I would just move to `data.table` though...

Comment: @nigmastar You miss the main difficulty here . Grouping is a secondary problem , You can use `tapply`,`by`,`plyr` or `data.table` ( even I will move to only in case I have a performance need). The main problem here is to get A UNIQUE INDEX FOR EACH GROUP.

Comment: yes, exactly, that's why I added the method using `unique` and then `merge` (more elegant) and, at the end of my answer, `tapply` + `as.numeric(factor(x))`. Both of them ensure each unique combination of `var1` and `var2` has the same `id`

Comment: well, I don't think you need... you seem far more experienced. Btw I just saw you are a .NET developer as well, would you be so kind to have a chat some day about a couple of things? (I won't steal you more then 10/15 min, I promise!)

Comment: I'm leaving the office basically now, can I add you on linkedin and chat there?

Answer (score 3):

In base `R` this does the job:

```
> df <- data.frame(var1=rep(c("A","B"), each=5), var2=LETTERS[1:5])
> head(df)
   var1 var2
1     A    A
2     A    B
3     A    C
4     A    D
5     A    E
6     B    A
> df$id<-unlist(tapply(df$var2, df$var1, seq_along))
> head(df)
   var1 var2 id
1     A    A  1
2     A    B  2
3     A    C  3
4     A    D  4
5     A    E  5
6     B    A  1
```

Using `data.table` instead:

```
library(data.table)

> dt <- data.table(var1=rep(c("A","B"), each=5), var2=LETTERS[1:5])
> dt[, id:=seq_along(var2), by=var1]
> head(dt)
    var1 var2 id
 1:    A    A  1
 2:    A    B  2
 3:    A    C  3
 4:    A    D  4
 5:    A    E  5
 6:    B    A  1
```

Both the techniques above described require your `var1` and `var2` **not** to have any duplicate value. In case this happens you can do the above against the distinct values of your `df` (saving these distinct values into `tmp`) and then joining the result to the original table:

```
> df <- data.frame(var1=rep(c("A","B"), each=5), var2=LETTERS[1:5])
> df <- rbind(df, df)
> df <- df[ order(df$var1, df$var2),]
> head(df)
   var1 var2
1     A    A
11    A    A
2     A    B
12    A    B
3     A    C
13    A    C
> tmp <- unique(df)
> head(tmp)
   var1 var2
1     A    A
2     A    B
3     A    C
4     A    D
5     A    E
6     B    A
> tmp$id<-unlist(tapply(tmp$var2, tmp$var1, seq_along))
> head(tmp)
   var1 var2 id
1     A    A  1
2     A    B  2
3     A    C  3
4     A    D  4
5     A    E  5
6     B    A  1
> df <- merge(df, tmp)
> head(df,10)
   var1 var2 id
1     A    A  1
2     A    A  1
3     A    B  2
4     A    B  2
5     A    C  3
6     A    C  3
7     A    D  4
8     A    D  4
9     A    E  5
10    A    E  5
```

I heaven't provided the columns by which to the join (merge in `R`) cause by default it's done accross all those with common name (i.e. `var1` then `var2`). In case you need to specify that:

```
merge(df, tmp, by=c("var1","var2")) # if the have same col names

merge(x=df, y=tmp, by.x=c("var1","var2"), by.y=c("var1","var2")) # if they don't. (not needed here)
```

Or, (just thought now), without using any join:

```
df$id <- tapply(df$var2, df$var1, function(x) as.numeric(factor(x)))
```